# Apache camel - How to use activemq Selective consumer using message body

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want two consumer with single activemq queue and wanted to filter while consuming. Selective is best option for me (please suggest if there is other). But sender does not sending me any header parameter or any property, selective only works with header or properties, now I wanted to filter message on message body . Is there any way to use selective with message body

My two messages body are differed by test and test2

```
{
   "test":{
      "abc":"123",
      "cde":"123"     
   }
}





{
   "test2":{
     "abc":"321",
     "cde":"321"
   }
}
```

I want something like selective with message body

```
from("jms:selective?selector=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(${body.test})).
    to("cxf:bean:replica01");

from("jms:selective?selector=" + java.net.URLEncoder.encode(${body.test2})).
    to("cxf:bean:replica02");
```

Please suggest if there is any way to do so.

Comment: Did my answer address your question? If so, please mark it as correct to help other users who have this same question in the future. If not, please elaborate as to why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As the [selector documentation for ActiveMQ 5.x](https://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html) points out, you can use XPath based selectors for messages which have XML bodies. However, the bodies of your messages aren't XML so there doesn't appear to be anyway to get the functionality you're looking for.

Keep in mind that as far as the broker is concerned the body of a message is just an array of bytes whereas message headers/properties are typed which allows for the kinds of comparison operations that make selectors viable.

Comment: Thanks you Justin for help, I know my body type is json so xpath will not work, so I am thinking of going through Filter and drop that in separate queue.